Name of a delay circuit
I'm hoping someone could help me out here.  I need the name of a circuit I can google or a schematic, that when a button is pushed; there is a 3 second delay, then a LED turns on for 5 seconds then shuts back off.  And it repeats that function every time the button is pushed.  Note, not the actual times, I just used those as an example.  I would expect to be able to adjust the times by changing a couple of resistors and capacitors.  I'm guessing it would use a 555 timer but I could be wrong.

There is no name for such a circuit. You could build one from multiple 555 chips but also a single MCU could be cheaper and more versatile.

This is just a canned comment to let you know that what you're trying to build from discrete analog components (possibly incorporating Opamps and/or NE555) is a digital control problem and thus can easily and with lower parts count be solved with a microcontroller with really minimal firmware to write.

a microcontroller with LED, switch and potentiometer

It sounds like you want two monostables in series.  There is no specific name for the combination.  Two questions:  a) Does the button have to be held down throughout the initial delay period?  2) If the button is released and re-pressed during the delay period, does the delay time go back to zero and restart of is the re-press ignored?  There are lots of ways to do what you want, but these change the nature of the first timer.  Are you married to the 555, or would prefer logic gates or comparators/opamps?

1:  No, The button is just a trigger to start the cycle.  2: Actual times will be in the micro seconds on the slow side and nano seconds on the fast side. The cycle will be completed long before it's triggered again.  I don't care if what is used, the 555 was just a guess.

ns on the fast side? Forget what I posted. Probably forget most MCUs too. This is specialized; you're asking for a timing solution 9 orders of magnitude more precise than your original question.

600-700ns on the fast side.  I found out a micro controller was too slow and I was hoping that simpler would be faster.

This is starting to sound like an XY question. I'm guessing the LED isn't the actual load/output since a 700ns flash would be borderline unobservable. Tell us the actual way it will be triggered, the actual durations involved, and what the circuit will actually be driving instead of getting answers for a completely different problem.

yeah, this makes no sense with a classical LED. Maybe with an modulated LED for data communications? Microcontrollers typically would be plenty fast for pulses like that, 600 ns is a many CPU cycles when you're running at, say, 48 MHz, which is not very fast for modern MCUs. Given, not all IOs are that fast, but it seems like a wrong statement to say "I found a micro controller was too slow".

Anyways, in your question you speak of seconds, now you speak of nanoseconds. Please fix your question to state what you really need. Voting to close as unclear until that's been fixed.

The LED isn't the load, just an indicator to test the circuit with longer/observable times. The output will go to a driver circuit to control some MOSFETS.   I apologize for being off on the actual time scale...I was trying to describe how I need the delay cycles.  I'm making a linear accelerator.  My approach is to have multiple copies of that circuit all tied to the same trigger.  Each one would have their own delays. They all will have a beginning delay in the micro seconds but the run delay will be in the micro second range at the beginning and 600-700ns at the end

When you say "linear accelerator", do you mean "coilgun"? There are guides for this; you don't need to start from first principles.

Ultimately yes, but I have some intermediates to go through.  I'm starting over with basic principles because I think there might be a flaw.  If you have a consistent a mass & delivering a consistent power, timing should be consistent and thus becomes key to higher speeds.  I was hoping that simpler might be faster & I thought there was a simple delay timer with the kind of cycle I described.   One where I might get the quick speeds I need by using very small caps.

Maybe it is a monostable multivibrator with some delay in it

I have guests staying in the room with the desktop computer so no schematic editor for me.

Something a little different than the usual cascade of 555s. Pressing S1 discharges C1 to zero and releasing it lets it charge up slowly through R1, which is the basis of your main timing network. I'm going to go ahead and say we want 3τ = 3s + 5s so τ ≈ 2.7s. 22 uF for C1 with 120k for R1 is within tolerances.
U1 and U2 are push-pull comparators with enough source/sink capability to run your LED (power supply connections not shown). A dual comparator shouldn't be too hard to find. R2, R3, and R4 set your "trip points". When the capacitor is fully discharged, both comparators have a low output, the LED is off. As C1 charges through R1, the voltage first rises above (+V•R4)/(R2+R3+R4); U2's output goes high and D1 turns on. Then, C1 charges above (+V(R3+R4))/(R2+R3+R4) and U1's output goes high, turning the LED off again.
This is not what I would really call a "professional level" design. It's sensitive to component tolerances and drift, S1 may run into contact erosion issues down the road, and as @justme said, a cheap MCU is much more versatile. But all the parts are exposed for you to tinker with and it does break you out of the mold of using 555s.

This is a good schematic, easy to read, clear and clean enough! Never apologize for hand-drawing something.

This question is a simple example of a Finite-State Machine (FSM) with analog computations for time.
All FSMs have five different states:

init
start
run
switch  (edge and state conditions) for repeating cycles
end

In your way of thinking, each time delay is called a "one-shot" or "1-shot," which has many implementations, including TTL 74LS123 and similar early CMOS small-scale integrated chips, Diode RCs using 1 of 6 inverters, clocked ring counters (Johnson counter).
The easy of changing delays can be done with a slider or rotary pot with large values to minimum current and low leakage electrolytic caps in the proper polarity.
Some logic is needed to determine your choice of edge trigger on pressing or releasing the switch. Then some other logic gate to accept your choice to ignore or accept another input switch to start a new cycle.
These choices are listed in what I call a "Design Spec."  This includes all your must have assumptions like battery or DC supply range, power or current output, LED specs or characteristics and anything you do not want to happen or everything you need to happen. That might include battery life or cost not to exceed, ease of construction method etc.
